# Management training help

Tags: management, training

I work at a relatively small business, but we are growing. Because of growth we hired a manager. This is his first time in a management position so of course there have been growing pains for him in his position. Recently, it came to my attention that some of his management skills have caused distrust among our employees. It should be noted that I am over training of employees and I was approached by a few employees with this issue. 
They don't feel like they can approach him with problems on the floor because when he talks with the person who is having the issue he will tell them who he heard the information from. "Well, so and so told me that you did this....." type of thing.

Are there any articles out there that anyone knows of that address this issue or things to help with some sort of management training?

Comment: Are you this persons boss?

Comment: I am not. I am the trainer for this company. However, the owner is family and I have brought up this issue with the him  and was asked to see if I could come up with anything training wise. In the meantime he would talk with the manager about things.

Answer (score 1):

This manager needs to be pulled aside for a friendly chat.  Preferably by someone above his level who he respects (or at least listens to).

"Hi Bob, I heard you out on the floor the other day and wanted to talk to you about something I heard.  I dont know if you are aware of it, but when you were talking to Steve you said you heard something from Stan.  I have found that this can lead to resentment on a team and one of the best ways I know to combat this is to always use I.  I noticed this or that never Stan told me you were.  After all if Stan says something to you wont you check it out yourself before you bring the criticism up to Steve?"

Manager are only as good as the managers they have had and learned from.  This person sounds like they need a good role model.

Comment: I am the trainer for this company. However, the owner is family and I have brought up this issue with him and was asked to see if I could come up with anything training wise. In the meantime he would talk with the manager about things. I'm hoping that by him talking to him will improve communication and trust issues among employees.

Answer (score 0):

I recently transitioned in to a management role in my company and before it started the company sent me to a full day seminar for people making that transition. It was hugely helpful. I happened to go to a Fred Pryor seminar, but I'm sure there are similar trainings put on my various companies all over.